# Xpath to get data before 2 <br> tags

Tags: html, xpath

I need to extract the text that comes before the 2 `<br>` tags, that is `text 3`. The code is similar to the following:

```
<div>
    <br>
    text1
    <br>
    text2
    <br>
    text3
    <br>
    <br>
    text4
    <br>
</div>
```

I tried `//div/text()[preceding-sibling::br]`, but, it extracts all the texts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding 2 consecutive `<br>`s in this scenario turns out to be trickier than I expected, because empty text node (the ones that consists of only whitespaces) need to be ignored here. This is one way :

```
/br[
    following-sibling::node()[self::*|self::text()[normalize-space()]
  ][1][self::br]]
```

The first predicate finds following sibling node, which type is either element node (`self::*`) or non-empty text node (`self::text()[normalize-space()]`). Then `[1]` takes only the first found node, and lastly `[self::br]` validates that the one found node is `<br>`.

The complete XPath expression would be as follow :

```
//div
 /br[
    following-sibling::node()[self::*|self::text()[normalize-space()]
  ][1][self::br]]
 /preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: Thanks again, i have never thought of combining xpaths. And thank you for the explanation too.